# Get value of custom attribute

Tags: jquery, radio-button, attr

I have two radio buttons. I would like to be able to get the value of the custom attribute "xmlvalue" of the checked radio button.

I have tried with the following script:

```
var userType = $("input[name=ctrl_CustomerType]:checked", this).attr('xmlvalue');
```

Markup:

```
<input type="radio" name="ctrl_CustomerType" id="ctrl_CustomerType_1" xmltag="CustomerType" xmlvalue="existingCustomer" checked="checked"> Yes
<br />
<input type="radio" name="ctrl_CustomerType" id="ctrl_CustomerType_2" xmltag="CustomerType" xmlvalue="newCustomer"> No
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NrQek/)

-- But I keep getting "Undefined".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Remove the context of your selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/NrQek/1/

```
 var userType = $("input[name=ctrl_CustomerType]:checked").attr('xmlvalue');
        alert("xmlvalue is: " + userType);
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks a lot. It works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is wrong.

The input element is not children of `a` element where you are clicking, so you cannot pass `this` as a context to the selector

```
var userType = $("input[name=ctrl_CustomerType]:checked").attr('xmlvalue');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V7UxV/)