# can't set values for checkbox attributes in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have group of checkbox in a table as,

```
 <input type="checkbox" id1='2' id2="" id3=""/>
```

gave a default value for id1 and initially value set as empty for id2 and id3. Is this right??
On a button action I am looping all these check boxes as,

```
                   $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
                         var $this = $(this);

                    });
```

In this action I have to assign values for id2 and id3(as empty before).
I tried many ways, but nothing worked.
Can anyone help??

Comment: Seems X-Y problem. And what are `id1, id2`??? these are invalid attribute

Comment: Is that wrong, giving like that? id2 and id3 set as empty initially

Comment: How do you try to get the value of the checkbox? You need something like `$(this).val()` Or do you try to get the value of id1, id2 and id3?

Comment: getting the value as `var id1=$this.attr("id1");`. But can't set to it

Comment: i think you should use data-id1=" " and get it with this code $(this).attr("data-id1")

Comment: So gettin the value works? Did you double check that with an alert or so? How do you try to set the attribute? For example id2

Comment: yes getting values works..!! tried to set values in different ways. `$('#'+id2).prop('id2', 20);` this is the one way that I tried

Comment: Im not sure if you can access custom html attributes like "id2" with #. You have to select the element in another way

Comment: can you suggest ?

Comment: You need to make the element selectable with a class or id. So you would need to add an attribute like class="myInput" or id="myInput". Then you can set the attribute id1 id2 or id3 Like this when using class a class as selector: `$('.myInput').attr('id2', '20');` Or if its already selected in your loop you can set it like `$(this).attr('id2', '20');` Maybe also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916503/get-value-of-custom-attribute)

Comment: @xDrago thank you, this works...!!!!